# Creating a JavaScript Snackbar from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've got some php script that is called when a simple 2 text field form is submitted. I'm attempting to 'create' a snackbar on the page from within the php to let the user know that their link was sent successfully, but it doesn't seem to be working at all.

I know that the snack bars are working fine as I've created them from within the page on load to test them. The php script also send the email every time so there's no issues there either.

Here's my php code:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['txtname'];
$link = $_POST['txtlink'];

// EMAIL STRUCTURE
$from = 'Banner Mastering';
$to = 'bannermastering@gmail.com';
$subject = "BannerMastering: You have a new download from $name";
$body ="From: $name\nDownload Link: $link";

//SEND EMAIL
if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
    echo '<script>
        $(function() {
            $.snackbar({content: "Your download link has been sent, thanks!", timeout: 10000});
        });
    </script>';


}
header("Location: http://www.bannermastering.co.uk/upload.html");
exit();
?>
```

I'm using Snackbar JS: https://github.com/FezVrasta/snackbarjs
And here is my page for context: http://www.bannermastering.co.uk/upload.html

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You're trying to mix a location header (browser redirect) with content, your redirect will have to be done by _JavaScript_ and you'll need to serve a full document (unless you're doing this by ajax). Also, you shouldn't be sending a header after content, isn't this throwing an error in the php?

Comment: Not to mention you can't output anything before setting headers

Comment: Cheers for the replies guys! I'm not sure what you mean by serve a full document, but i've tried to move my redirect in javascript now like you said. I've tried using the `window.location.replace` and .href method, but neither seem to be working, any more help would great!

`if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)){
echo '
    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
    $(function() {
     $.snackbar({content: "Your download link has been sent, thanks!", timeout: 10000});
    });
 window.location.replace("http://www.bannermastering.co.uk/upload.html");
    </script>';
}
?>`

Answer (score 0):

Try and instantiate:

```
$(function() {
    $.snackbar({content: "Your download link has been sent, thanks!", timeout: 10000});
});
```

as a function to be ready to be called on the page load, that way it's in the DOM, then have the callback trigger it.